# What does this joke about milk going bad mean?

Tags: meaning, jokes

This is a joke from the TV series "Friends".

> — Can I borrow this? My milk's gone bad.
>   — I hate that. I once had a thing of half-and-half. Stole my car.

I'm thinking that it has something to do with the ambiguity of "gone bad", but I don't understand what "I once had a thing of half-and-half" means.

Comment: I think your intuition is right. It's a bit of a strange joke. I don't find it very funny really.

Comment: The joke would be clearer if the word 'thing' were replaced by 'container'.

Comment: Seems to me more like '***tin*** of half-and-half', the latter being milk-and-cream in the US.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Half and half is [a mixture of half milk and half cream.](http://www.food.com/library/half-and-half-445)

I would say that the joke (as you believe) is

- My milk has gone bad
- That happened to me once. My ('irrelevant to the joke' choice of) milk was so bad that it stole my car

Not a particularly good joke, **edit** (though now I think I remember it from Friends, I think the delivery would have saved it. Chandler, if I am not wrong)

Comment: Yes, Chandler, but he's not the only one.  Ross's quondam father-in-law (Ron Leibman) once complained to him about the ongoing corrosion of his sailboat. "You know what rust is, Ross?  It's boat *cancer*!"  Ross sympathizes, "As a kid, I lost a bike to that once."  ObEnglishSE content: "to lose X to" means to have a loved one die of some particular cause or affliction.  "We lost their father to heart disease."

Answer (score 31):

The joke turns on two different means of the phrase "goes bad."

When milk "goes bad," it spoils. When a person "goes bad," they commit a crime, such as stealing a car.

As johnc mentioned, half and half is a mixture of milk and cream, and it can also spoil.

Comment: The television series "Breaking Bad" started airing January 2008.  Given this context, this is a really funny exchange.